# Boolean not applying correctly

Tags: java, boolean

Alrighty, so I have a program that is supposed to take the first name of the customer, and regardless if the letters in the name are capitalized or lower case, if they are Mike or Diane, it sets the discount to being true and then later on applies the discount. By default discount = false.

Heres getting the name and setting discount to true:

```
if (firstName == "Mike" || firstName == "Diane")
  {
     discount = true;
  }
```

And here's later on when I'm trying to apply the discount and lower the cost:

```
if (discount == true)
  {
     System.out.println("You are eligible for a $2.00 discount!");
     cost = cost - (2.00);
  }
```

However the problem is that when I use Mike or Diane, whether capitalizing or not, it simply does not apply the discount to the price. It compiles and runs, it just doesn't apply the discount.

Comment: Use `String`'s `equals` method to compare string values, not the `==` operator.

Comment: 1) take a look at [how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). 2) don't use `if (discount==true)`. Just write it as `if(discount)`. This way you will never make mistakes like `if (discount = true)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.equals(...)` to compare `String` values:

```
"Mike".equals(firstName)
```

`==` compares the references of Java Objects.  It's perfectly fine to use `==` to compare ***primitive data types*** values (ex.  `boolean`, `int`, `double`, etc.).

If you want to ignore the case of the characters, then use `.equalsIgnoreCase(...)`:

```
"Mike".equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)
```

[Check out the String API, it has a lot of useful methods.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: This is not case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `==` (reference equality) for determining String equality, luckily there is an [String#equalsIgnoreCase(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
boolean discount = ("Mike".equalsIgnoreCase(firstName) || 
    "Diane".equalsIgnoreCase(firstName));
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` compares the reference of the strings. You can use equals:

**Solution:**

```java
if(firstName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mike") || firstName.equalsIgnoreCase("Diane"))
{
    discount = true;
}
```

**Tip:**

Nevertheless, it is better to write `"Mike".equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)` instead of `firstName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mike")`, because you are sure that `Mike` is not `null`. `firstName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mike")` can throw a `NullPointerException` if `firstName` is `null`.

Comment: Does not ignore case.

Comment: Yes he should use the method you gave in your answer. I edit my post, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use equalIgnoreCase Method

```
"Mike".equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)
```

like

```
if(firstName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mike") || firstName.equalsIgnoreCase("Diane"))
    {
        discount = true;
    }
```